# Pandas: Get average value of previous date-times from multiple groupbys

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the average value from previous dates if 2 conditions are met and it is within a time-period (let's say 5 days).

As an example; If the 2 condition columns are (1) id and (2)country and the values of those in the current row are USA and 1 respectively. Then I want to do a search for other rows within the previous 5 days and where USA and 1 also exists in those rows.

(note: I want to exclude the value of the current row, only the mean value from previous rows should be inserted).

At last, I want to calculcate the average value (for another column) for those rows and have this inserted into a new column for the current row.

I have been using some code that work for a single groupby column, but does not (as intended) work for multiple columns. Below is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = {
    'date': ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'],
    'id':[1,2,2,1],
    'country': ['USA','Germany','USA','USA'],
    'value': [2,4,5,3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
grouped_by = ['country','id']
df_resampled = df.groupby(grouped_by).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('1D').first())

df1 = df_resampled.groupby(level=0)['value']. \
    apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=5).mean()). \
    reset_index(name="previous_5_day_average_value")

merged = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['date','id','country'], how='left')
print(merged)
```

The intended output should be this:

```
        date  id  country  value  previous_5_day_average_value
0 2019-01-01   1      USA      2                           NaN
1 2019-01-02   2  Germany      4                           NaN
2 2019-01-03   2      USA      5                           NaN
3 2019-01-04   1      USA      3                           2
```

Only the last row should have 2 as a value as that is the first time that both the country (USA) and the id (1) is repeated within the previous 5 days. However the output I am getting is the following:

```
        date  id  country  value  previous_5_day_average_value
0 2019-01-01   1      USA      2                           NaN
1 2019-01-02   2  Germany      4                           NaN
2 2019-01-03   2      USA      5                           2.0
3 2019-01-04   1      USA      3                           3.5
```

Can someone help me to get the desired output?

Comment: Why the previous_5_day_average_value is 2 in the expected result?

Comment: the first row has the same country and id as the last row. The value in the first row is 2 and it the observation happened 3 days prior (so within the 3-day period). So all conditions are met

Comment: I mean how the value 2 is calculated? if you take the average of 2 and 3, should that be 2.5?

Comment: Sorry for not specifiying this, but it should only look at previous rows. It shouldn't include the value for the current row. So there is only one observation (2) that fits these criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Initial df**

```
        date  id  country  value
0 2019-01-01   1      USA      2
1 2019-01-02   2  Germany      4
2 2019-01-03   2      USA      5
3 2019-01-04   1      USA      3
4 2019-01-12   1      USA      3
```

---

**Creating resample DataFrame  by Day, Country and ID**

```
df2 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby(['country','id'])['country','id']
         .resample('D')
         .ffill()
         .join(df.set_index(['country','id','date'])) 
         .reset_index(level = [0,1],drop=True))
print(df2)

           country  id  value
date                          
2019-01-02  Germany   2    4.0
2019-01-01      USA   1    2.0
2019-01-02      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-03      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-04      USA   1    3.0
2019-01-05      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-06      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-07      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-08      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-09      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-10      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-11      USA   1    NaN
2019-01-12      USA   1    3.0
2019-01-03      USA   2    5.0
```

---

**applying rolling + shift**

```
new_df = df.join(df2.groupby(['country','id'])
                    .value
                    .rolling(5,min_periods=1)
                    .mean()
                    .groupby(level = [0,1])
                    .shift()
                    .rename('previous_5_day_average_value'),
                 on =['country','id','date']
)
print(new_df)



        date  id  country  value  previous_5_day_average_value
0 2019-01-01   1      USA      2                           NaN
1 2019-01-02   2  Germany      4                           NaN
2 2019-01-03   2      USA      5                           NaN
3 2019-01-04   1      USA      3                           2.0
4 2019-01-12   1      USA      3                           NaN
```

**Compact code**

```
new_df = df.join(df.set_index('date')
                   .groupby(['country','id'])['country','id']
                   .resample('D')
                   .ffill()
                   .join(df.set_index(['country','id','date'])) 
                   .reset_index(level = [0,1],drop=True)
                   .groupby(['country','id'])
                   .value
                   .rolling(5,min_periods=1)
                   .mean()
                   .groupby(level = [0,1])
                   .shift()
                   .rename('previous_5_day_average_value'),
                    on =['country','id','date'])
```

Comment: Hello not completely sure how this would work. If I run this directly instead of the code I used I am not getting the same output. Also rolling does not work on the original data-set because there might be multiple rows with same dats. Hence the resampling process.

Comment: the problem you need group by both level not only level=0 if there more column select value before rolling, check updated solution:)

Comment: `(df.groupby(['country','id'])
           .value
           .rolling(5,min_periods=1)
           .mean()
           .groupby(level = [0,1])
           .shift())`

Comment: hello tried the updated code. if i change the date to 2019-01-12 the last value should NaN as well (since no other rows were observed within the last 5 days).

Comment: keep in mind that tried to avoid using apply because it is really slow

Comment: Yes I accepted the answer, however I did notice that I am getting ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit when running it on sample where datetime, country and id are all the same.

Comment: I have not contemplated that case because if you have the same country id and date as you choose the previous value ?,
 in that case you could previously do something like `df.assign (count = df.groupby (['country', 'date', 'id']). cumcount ())` and then use count to distinguish between duplicates.